# How to change the pathname of the url in node js

Tags: node.js, parsing, pathname

I need to change the url pathname
for example:

the current url is

"http://localhost/pages/catalog/catalog.html"

I need to remove the "pages" so it will show like

"http://localhost/catalog/catalog.html"

Answer (score 0):

Depends on Your build, without any details I can advice to use Express framework with router initialized, which You can find [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). Then You can specify Your url path.